# catch ajax request errors and replace with custom message

Tags: jquery, ajax

**UPDATE**: run this and take a look at you developer console! You will see error 429 and custom error handled message!

```js
setInterval(() => {
  $.ajax({
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": `https://us1.locationiq.com/v1/search?key=pk.55397e7aa188d68fc571ccc54f9eea44&q=empire state&format=json&limit=50`,
    "method": "GET"
  }).done(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }).fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
    //i want to display only this
    console.log('fail')
  });
}, 500)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I have an ajax call, what i am doing is submitting a GET request to a remote url and it works fine. What im trying to achieve is if i get back an error I want to log `fail` instead of logging the actual error message received from the response in the console. How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

```js
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": `urlPath`,
  "method": "GET"
}


$.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
$.ajax(settings).fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
  //i want to display only this
  console.log('fail')
});
```

Comment: How specifically is this not working as expected?  When an HTTP error response code is received, `fail()` should be triggered, but not `done()`.  Are you observing otherwise?  When you debug, what is the HTTP code for the response?

Comment: yeah that's what i thought too but in my case i get the custom log which is ```fail``` and the error from the response too. The error i am getting is error ```429``` which is sent back from the server when you call it again and again too fast. @David

Comment: [Works for me.](https://jsfiddle.net/9me6kfho/)  If you swap the `method` between `GET` and `POST` you can make the request fail or succeed.  In each case, only one of the callbacks is invoked.

Comment: @David take a look at the update above

Comment: Aside from the error handling, you're most likely seeing the 429 response because you're calling the API endpoint every 500ms, which is a really bad idea.

Comment: Don't call `$.ajax()` twice. Call it once and chain the `.done()` and `.fail()` callbacks.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thats just to show you that the error isn't getting custom handled. This is just a test senario.

Comment: @Barmar its the same. I get the same error too. Updated my code to your preferred method though.

Comment: @seriously: It still works as expected for me.  Each *individual* call to the API is logging *either* the success *or* the fail.  Not both.  It's not really clear what the problem is.

Comment: @David He's not saying that he gets both the success and fail log messages. He's saying that when it fails he gets both the real error message and also "fail". I think this is just the browser's default error reporting -- it logs HTTP errors automatically.

Comment: @David what Barmar said

Comment: @seriously: So this really has nothing to do with jQuery or the code written, you're just looking to suppress the browser's behavior of logging HTTP errors to the console?

Comment: @David I mean my thought was I can catch the error and handle it through ajax but by what im seeing thats not possible.

Comment: @seriously: I wouldn't expect so.  My guess is that error is logged to the console by the browser before control is even handed back to JavaScript to invoke the callback.

Comment: @David would that differer if I used ```http.get(url, function (response) {response.on('error', function (err) {console.log('fail'); }); });``` instead?

Comment: @seriously: Bearing in mind that my assumptions could very well be wrong, based on my understanding.... No.  If the browser is logging that error to the console before handing control back to the JavaScript engine then by definition it wouldn't matter what JavaScript code is used.